# Operating on selected columns of dataframe in R, without affecting other columns

Tags: r

What I would like to do is to take a dataframe, let's call it x and apply a function y to only some of the columns. I need to be able to easily specify which columns to operate on -hopefully by passing the column numbers as vector or list.

For example, I may wish to add 10 to columns 1,3,5, and 6, but leave columns 2 and 4 unchanged.

I suspect I'll need to use the apply function - it's the details of how to do this I'm unsure of.

Any guidance here would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What if say I wanted to find the means of some the columns, and medians of the other columns - but want an output vector of these means and medians such that the first entry of the vector corresponds to the first column of the dataframe?

Comment: Update your question, showing an example of what you want and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `[<-`. It is vectorised, e.g.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(   V1 = sample(5),
            V2 = sample(5),
            V3 = sample(5),
            V4 = sample(5) )
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  2  1  5  5
2  4  3  2  1
3  5  4  3  4
4  3  2  4  3
5  1  5  1  2

df[ , c(1,4) ]  <- df[ , c(1,4)] + 10

  V1 V2 V3 V4
1 12  1  5 15
2 14  3  2 11
3 15  4  3 14
4 13  2  4 13
5 11  5  1 12
```

Using column numbers is generally thought of as bad practice. What if the ordering changes in future file versions etc? Better to use names, e.g. `c("V1" , "V4")` then the ordering does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[<-` as in

```
> set.seed(1)
> df <- data.frame(A=1:5, B=sample(0:9, 5), C=sample(0:9, 5), 
+                  D=sample(0:9, 5), E=sample(0:9, 5), F=sample(0:9, 5))
> df
  A B C D E F
1 1 2 8 2 4 9
2 2 3 9 1 6 1
3 3 4 5 5 7 5
4 4 6 4 9 2 0
5 5 1 0 4 9 8
> # Adding 10 to columns 1,3 and 5
> df[, c(1,3,5)] <- df[, c(1,3,5)]+10
> df
   A B  C D  E F
1 11 2 18 2 14 9
2 12 3 19 1 16 1
3 13 4 15 5 17 5
4 14 6 14 9 12 0
5 15 1 10 4 19 8
```